# Run excel add in when workbook opens and pass the activeworkbook to add in

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

Need some advice on running an excel add in. I have created an excel add in that, checks workbooks opened by users and determines if the excel opened by user has code behind it. This bit works fine.

However, what i dont know is how to pass the workbook opened by the user to the add in and run the code in the addin.

Please help.

Thanks,
Navin

Comment: You mean you are looking for the trigger to run this script in your add in only when an (additional) workbook is openen?

Answer (score 1):

Googling this problem delivered me this comprehensive link which suggests making use of  Application Events:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

Comment: similar questions have been asked in the past, and I see the link I posted is used there with good result!